# How many dimensions will a derivative of a 1-D vector by a 2-D matrix have?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

As the title above, I find it hard to imagine or illustrate. It is a question from Coursera and the answer is 3. I do not get it why the answer is 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental rule of the derivative is that final derivative will always consist of derivatives of each output component by each input component. Imagine your 1D vector is [a1, a2, a3]. and 2D matrix is [[k1 k2][k3 k4]]. your derivative for each term in 2D will be a 1D vector i.e. 1D for k1, 1D for K2, 1D for K3 and 1D for K4. So if you arrange them in the matrix you will need 3 dimensions.